# Invalid 'path' Argument Type Error in multer.js File Upload

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I want to prevent duplicate file storage using the following code. However, I can't access the 'path' argument in the file object.

Here's my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const multer = require("multer");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const type = file.mimetype.split("/")[0];
    const path = `./upload/${req.user._id}/${type}`;
    fs.mkdirSync(path, { recursive: true });
    cb(null, path);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);

    stream.on("data", (data) => {
      hash.update(data);
    });

    stream.on("end", () => {
      const fileHash = hash.digest("hex");
      const fileName = `${fileHash}${file.originalname}`;
      cb(null, fileName);
    });

    stream.on("error", (error) => {
      cb(error);
    });
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

,"error":{"code":"ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE"},"exception":true,"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined\nTypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined\n at new ReadStream (node:internal/fs/streams:171:5)\n at Object.createReadStream (node:fs:2935:10)\n at DiskStorage.filename [as getFilename] (D:\chatAppServer\src\middleware\middlewareUploads.js:32:23)\n at D:\chatAppServer\node_modules\multer\storage\disk.js:34:10\n at DiskStorage.destination [as getDestination]

Answer (score 1):

A long shot, but I will give this a try.
stream.on("end") event is asynchronous and there's a chance that When you call cb(null, fileName) inside the stream.on("end") event, the filename function may have already returned, and Multer has moved on to other operations. As a result  the fileName variable is undefined, leading to the "path" argument error. 
you can use Multer's file.buffer property to access the file contents as a Buffer.

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const hash = crypto.createHash("sha256")
    hash.update(file.buffer) // Use file.buffer to calculate the hash directly.

    const fileHash = hash.digest("hex")
    const fileName = `${fileHash}${file.originalname}`
    cb(null, fileName)
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
The approach I took to retrieve the file buffer was actually wrong. To obtain the file buffer before uploading, I needed to set the value of the variable `storage` to `multer.memoryStorage()` like this:

```javascript
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();

const upload = multer({
  storage,
});
```
Soon, I will make this part of my project open source on GitHub and share the link below this post.